# Visitor groups using Viewed Pages criterion not working

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I am working on a page which should use visitor groups to personalize its contents. However, I cannot seem to get the Visited Page criterion to match.

I assume that the Visited Page criteron uses the class `EPiServer.Personalization.VisitorGroups.Criteria.ViewedPagesCriterion`, which stores the viewed pages in the HttpContext session with the key `EPiServer:ViewedPages`. Unfortunately, the session key doesn't seem to be added at all when I enter the specified pages.

Has anyone got any idea why it isn't working?

---

**EDIT:** I have now tried to implement the Criterion myself, bascially using the decompiled code from `EPiServer.Personalization.VisitorGroups.Criteria.ViewedPagesCriterion`. It turns out that the criterion subscribes [to a `VisitedPage` event](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=episerverframework/7/18d69bd8-cf04-d5ba-8aaa-b2cd9b949aca) which is supposedly raised when a page is visited. By debugging, I have determined that the event subscription is successful, but the event handler is never called. This means that, for some reason, EPiServer does not raise the event.

I tried to subscribe to the [`StartRequest` event](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=episerverframework/7/e4d54b5c-78ab-b438-9a6a-320dcf778866) instead, and in this case the handler *is* called. This begs the question: Why is the `VisitedPage` event not raised when visiting pages?

Comment: Do you have outputcaching activated? You should use httpCacheExpiration="0:0:0" with VisitorGroups I assume.

Comment: Outputcaching is disabled. I tried using httpCacheExpiration as you explained, but no difference.

Comment: Which version are you using? MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: @JohanKronberg I am using MVC.

Comment: @JohanKronberg I have investigated further and have some interesting findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VisitedPage` event is fired only when a page is shown through a controller which has the `ViewedPageCriterionAttribute`. The base controller  `EPiServer.Web.Mvc.PageController<T>` provided by EPiServer has this attribute, so the it works when controllers inherit from this controller.

If you do not wish to use `PageController`, the attribute has to be used on your custom controller:

```
[ViewedPageCriterion]
public class MyController<T> : Controller<T> where T : IDefaultModel
{
    // controller implementation
}
```